How to export merge multi image to one page two sides (2 by 5) in A4 size output in VB.NET
I'm Trying to export merge multi image to one page two sides (2 by 5) in A4 size output in VB.NET.
So the total image is 10 in 1 A4 page
Please Guide Me
Thanks
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private PATH As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim img1 As Image = Image.FromFile(PATH & "\ExportedBusinessCard0.png")
        Dim img2 As Image = Image.FromFile(PATH & "\ExportedBusinessCard0.png")
        Dim b As Bitmap = MergeImages(img1, img2, 10)
    End Sub
    Private Function MergeImages(ByVal image1 As Image, ByVal image2 As Image, ByVal space As Integer) As Bitmap
        Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(image1.Width + image2.Width + space, Math.Max(image1.Height, image2.Height))
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
            g.Clear(Color.White)
            g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0)
            g.DrawImage(image2, image1.Width + space, 0)
        End Using
        Dim img As Image = bitmap

        img.Save(PATH & "\A4twoside.jpg")
        Return bitmap
    End Function


End Class


Result from code

Sample Image

Desired output


You need to iterate over the images by number; let us call the iterator i. The x-position will be (i mod 2) * columnWidth + leftMargin and the y-position will be i \ 5 * rowHeight + topMargin. A backslash does integer division in VB.NET. I recommend using pencil and paper to work out how to also include padding.

@AndrewMorton , Thank you for your reply and can you answer as an answer
